# How connect mBot Ranger through bluetooth on linux

Tags: networking, 18.04, bluetooth

I got an mBot Ranger and it works fine to program with my Ubuntu 18.4 LTS with the makebot-ide. The problem is that I have to use an USB-cable. Makebot doesn't support bluetooth for Linux. So I guess that I have to make a bluetooth connection and setup that connection as a com-port somehow.

I can connect though the ubuntu-gui (although it doesn't for the pincode as the manual for windows says should be there) so the bot is visible. 
I have tried a few guides to get the com-port, eg /dev/rfcomm0 but I have not been successfull in getting it to work (or exist at all).